# include sp.core.js in spfx webpart

Tags: spfx

How do I include sp.core.js in my webpart? I tried this in the config

```
 "externals": {
    "@microsoft/sp-client-base": "node_modules/@microsoft/sp-client-base/dist/sp-client-base.js",
    "@microsoft/sp-client-preview": "node_modules/@microsoft/sp-client-preview/dist/sp-client-preview.js",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "node_modules/@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset/dist/sp-lodash-subset.js",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "node_modules/office-ui-fabric-react/dist/office-ui-fabric-react.js",
    "react": "node_modules/react/dist/react.min.js",
    "react-dom": "node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.min.js",
    "react-dom/server": "node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom-server.min.js",
    "spcore":"https://static.sharepointonline.com/bld/_layouts/15/16.0.5708.1207/sp.core.js"
```

},

and in my webpart I put

> import {sp}  from "spcore";

but it says spcore could not be found. I am trying to get access to the sp.permissionkind enum.

thanks

Comment: ok, I found it in https://sharepoint.github.io/classes/_sp_client_base_.sppermission.html